# Probability and risk factors (estimation)

Tags: probability

A friend came up with a question I cannot answer. The assumptions:

- the probability of contracting a disease with no risk factors is
  $p_0$;
- the probability in presence of risk factor 1 is $p_1$
- the probability in presence of risk factor 2 is $p_2$

how could one estimate $p_{12}$, the probability to contract the disease in presence of both risk factors?

Comment: You would need more information. Here are some examples of additional information that might be useful (not all of it is needed, but some subset would be): Given someone has risk factor 2, what is the probability they also have risk factor 1? Given someone has risk factor 1, what is the probability they also have risk factor 2? Given someone has the disease, what is the probability they have risk factor 1 or 2? Is there a correlation between risk factors 1 and 2 and what is the correlation coefficient? Note: This list is not comprehensive.

Comment: Note: $p_{1\text{ and }2} = p_1+p_2-p_{1\text{ or }2}$.

Comment: I also guessed more information was needed. This is already a good starting point, thanks!

Comment: My current estimate is $p_{12}=p_1+p_2-p_1 p_2$: it is a probability (between 0 and 1), has maximum at $p_1=p_2=1$, for which it is equal to 1. It is symmetric in $p_1, p_2$. The extension to 3 risk factors, obtained iteratively has similar properties. Does it make sense?